# Using open() such that the file permission is guaranteed to be the same as that of files written out using the NSData file write methods

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, file, permissions

I'm currently using `open()` in the following way to write out a file:

```
NSString *path = @"/Users/enchilada/Desktop/file.txt";
int fd = open([path fileSystemRepresentation],
              O_EXCL | O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,
              S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
```

My issue is the 3rd parameter. Is it “correct” in the sense that it’s guaranteed to yield the exact same permission under all circumstances as `NSData`’s regular `writeToFile:` methods?

I want to obtain the appropriate “default” permissions when using a plain `open()` instead of using Cocoa’s methods to write out files.

I have found the above permissions (rw-rw-rw-) to work, because the **umask actually brings them down** to (rw-r--r--). But my question is: Is this always guaranteed? What should my 3rd parameter actually be?

Comment: I think typically you pass `0644` (e.g. rw-r--r--) as the permissions to `open()` when you have no particular need for different permissions. I can only guess but I'd assume that's what `NSData` does.

Comment: Yeah that wouldn’t be a bad guess, but I want to be completely sure ;)

Comment: The only way to be completely sure is to somehow get source access to Foundation, and you'll never have that. However, if you want a more low-level way to access files but still using Cocoa, you could use [NSFileHandle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/), which provides a class method that will create a file at a path and open it for writing. One can assume this uses the same default permissions as NSData's method.

Comment: I was actually about to use NSFileHandle, but started wondering whether it’s as fast as open() and write() calls. It’s pretty repetitive and intensive this stuff I’m doing…

Comment: The only way to know that is to profile it. You may be doing a lot of file access, but I suspect the CPU overhead of an object-oriented wrapper around file access is a lot smaller than the actual overhead of doing I/O, period.

Comment: @KevinBallard No. You typically pass 0666 as the permissions to `open()` when you have no particular need for different permissions.  The user’s umask then modifies this (users generally have this set to 0022, hence 0644 being the usual permissions for a new file). See [umask(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/umask.2.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find out using `dtruss`.  Here's my test program:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[NSData dataWithBytes:"hello\n" length:6] writeToFile:@"/tmp/data.out" atomically:NO];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my run log:

```
$ sudo dtruss ~/Library/Dev*/Xcode/De*/datatest-*/B*/P*/D*/datatest 2>&1 | fgrep data.out
open("/tmp/data.out\0", 0x601, 0x1B6)        = 3 0
```

Hex 0x1B6 is octal 0666.

Comment: Oh, that’s sweet! Which OS are you running? I’m running Snow Leopard and I get the same results as you for both the 2nd and 3rd parameters. It would be nice to know whether the parameters are the same on Lion.

Comment: Also, given say 0x601 for the 2nd parameter, how do I as quickly as possible determine which flags (O_WRONLY, O_CREAT, or what have you) it’s actually combined from? (I’m not too good at working with numbers in different bases…)

Comment: I'm using 10.7.2, but it's very likely the same on all versions of OS X and iOS.  You can convert between hex and octal easily using OS X's Calculator.  Just do View > Programmer.  The O_* flags are defined in `/usr/include/sys/fcntl.h`.  `0x601 = O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes 0666 is correct (at least for iOS 5), but the 2nd argument would be `O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY` if you're not writing atomically (and `O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR` on the temporary file if written atomically.)

Actually you could run your program in a debugger, set a break point at `open`, and then check the 3rd argument (`p/o $r2` in gdb for ARM) to ensure.

Comment: I tried setting a symbolic breakpoint at open, but it's not breaking when calling NSData’s writeToFile:atomically: It just writes out the file as normally, but doesn't break at all.

Comment: @Enchilada: Perhaps the name is not open (in some OS X `open` is internally known as `open$UNIX2003`). Try `rb ^open` to break on all symbols that starts with 'open'. Use `disa` to disable all, and `ena` to enable all breakpoints.

Comment: I’m indeed on a Mac, and you’re right. It now breaks at open$UNIX2003. However, if I type in "p/o $r2" all it prints out is "$1 = Value can't be converted to integer." Any ideas?